# Changing response headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am learning ASP.NET Core and for that I am trying to implement a simple proxy server. 
Setup idea: 
I will set the proxy settings of my browser to point to my server (currently localhost). The server will duplicate the http request and send to the intended server and receive the request. Then the original response header will be edited to match the received header from the actual request and sent to the client.
example: I type http://bing.com in my browser --> the proxy settings will take this request to my server --> I will create a http request called tempRequest with values from the original request --> the tempRequest is sent and a tempResponse is received from http://bing.com --> I will edit the original Http response to match tempResponse --> send the modified response to the browser.

I am trying to achieve this using middleware.
So far, I think I am successfully getting the response back from the original server (http://bing.com). I am having some trouble sending this received response to the browser.

Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();           

        app.UseProxyServer();
    }
}
```

Middleware implementation:

```
public static class ProxyMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseProxyServer(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ProxyMiddleware>();
    }
}

public class ProxyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ProxyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalRequest = context.Request;

        var absoluteUri = string.Concat(
                    originalRequest.Scheme,
                    "://",
                    originalRequest.Host.ToUriComponent(),
                    originalRequest.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
                    originalRequest.Path.ToUriComponent(),
                    originalRequest.QueryString.ToUriComponent());

        if(!absoluteUri.Contains("localhost"))
        {
            HttpWebRequest newRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(absoluteUri);

            //Make a copy of the original request
            CopyRequestTo(context.Request, newRequest);

            //Get a response using the copied http request.
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)await newRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            //Modify the response going back to the browser to match the response 
            //received from the intended server.
            CopyResponseTo(response, context);
        }
        await this._next(context);
    }

    private void CopyResponseTo(HttpWebResponse source, HttpContext destination)
    {
        destination.Response.OnStarting(async() =>
        {
            await source.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(destination.Response.Body);
            foreach (string headerKey in source.Headers.AllKeys)
            {
                //============Exception Here=========
                destination.Response.Headers[headerKey] = source.Headers.Get(headerKey);
            }

            destination.Response.StatusCode = (int)source.StatusCode;
        });
    }

    public static void CopyRequestTo(HttpRequest source, HttpWebRequest destination)
    {
        destination.Method = source.Method;
        foreach (var headerKey in source.Headers.Keys)
        {
            destination.Headers[headerKey] = source.Headers[headerKey];               
        }

        destination.ContentType = source.ContentType;

        if (source.Method != "GET" && source.Method != "HEAD" && source.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var destinationStream = destination.GetRequestStream();                
            source.Body.CopyTo(destinationStream);
            destinationStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But while changing the response I get this exception:

> Headers are read only, response has already started

Why this exception even when I am using `Response.OnStarting` ?

I am running the application from console ( not using IIS )

Comment: You may look into ASP.NET Core [ProxyMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy) implementation,  to learn how to do simple proxy server. By the way, middleware creates new HttpRequest instance, when proxying request: [CreateProxyHttpRequest method](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyAdvancedExtensions.cs#L41-L70)

Comment: Yes I could have followed that GitHub page, but I am making this just for learning.